# How to store image tiles in file system for leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i got a link which try to explain how to store image tiles in file system but not very clear to me. here is the url
http://build-failed.blogspot.in/2012/11/zoomable-image-with-leaflet.html

just see this image [image]

just seen many sub folder has been created as per image but do not understand what they try to point out with arrow images ?

how this `eso / «z» / «x» / «y».jpg` is related with images folder structure?
1) why zero folder is consider as z ?
2) why zero and one sub folder in parent folder called one is consider as x ?
1) why 0.png and 1.png images are consider as y ?

the above three things is not clear due to lack of explanation. what is the relation there ?

if some one already knows it or do understand then please share the knowledge with me. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I'll try to explain.

First z = zoom level, x=longitude, y=latitude

Longitude and latitude are not real value taken from the map projection but grid indexes.

The way you store the tiles is like this:

1. First parent folder: z (zoom level)
2. Child folders: all x at this zoom level
3. Images names: all y at this x position and this zoom level

If you want to store for instance the following tile: /0/0/0.png

- Folder: 0
- Subfolder: 0
- 0.png

At zoom level 0, habitually there is only on tile for the whole world so only a subfolder 0 (for the x) and an image 0.png (for the y). At each zoom level the number of images increase exponentially.

For the /12/6/7.png

- Folder: 12
- Subfolder: 6
- 7.png

Feel free to ask for more details if something is not clear.

Comment: thanks for answer. now can u refer any c# sample code which will create tile of my big images following the convention of above image i posted.

Comment: sorry to ask you a question that previously you worked with leaflet.js for loading custom images instead of map images?

Comment: I dont know any tool in c# to do so, but GDAL2Tiles is a simple bash command tool in python that will do the job.

Comment: can u tell me any url from where i can download all tile images of a big image. so i may understand how to generate file writing c# routine. thanks

Comment: maybe you'll find what you are looking for in this blog: http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/gameprog.html

Comment: i roughly see your last link.....looking promising but like to know does that code will generate image following the same convention as per my images pasted in my post?

Comment: I cant say, but probably. Try with zoom level 0 to 3 at first. It will takes few seconds to generate the tiles

Comment: sorry to ask....what is zoom level? can we put all slice pics in folder and refer that folder in leaflet.js.......is it possible? if yes then can u post a sample code of similar of leaflet.js. thanks

Comment: zoom level is kind of the scale of the map. Leaflet have predetermined scale you can zoom in and zoom out. Zoom level 0 is the farther you can go. As far as you zoom in, the zoom level increase. No you cant just put all the tiles in a single folder.

Comment: sorry to ask so many questions here. i have seen leaflet can load a single image. here is one link http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/kj9sLt07/2/. my objective : i could load a huge big image by leaflet but it may take long time and that is why i am after slice images. basically i want to load slice images and let user to navigate by dragging. when user drag left/right or up/down then other part of image will be visible and i want leaflet should load other part slice on fly when will be required. so please guide me how to achieve it.

Comment: please share knowledge if u know....z is for zoom but what zoom does in leaflet js? when we specify url localhost/tileserver{z}/{x}/{y}.png for loading tile image then what z does? anyone can elaborately explain the meaning of z/x/y ?